# Is there any way to translate thingsboard user dashboard to other languages like Japanese in community edition?

Tags: translation, thingsboard

I am new to thingsboard and I don't know its features. is it possible to change texts in the dashboard? should I change from the source code? is it too hard. I don't want to translate all the text in thingsboard, just things that customer user may see.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's unclear if you want to:

1. Translate default text from the default features in Thingsboard
2. or translate your own custom *Strings* in some of your dashboards for different customers

If 1. is your case, Thingsboard automatically translates it's texts to the default language on the web-browser of the user. You can customize translations in *White Labeling -> Custom Translations*

If 2. is what you want, you'll have to use custom widgets, and implement the *$translate* service to manage titles, labels and other texts in your widgets.
The input widgets have some examples on how to implement translations in your widgets.

```
var $translate = self.ctx.$scope.$injector.get('$translate');
var utils = self.ctx.$scope.$injector.get('utils');
var title = utils.customTranslation(self.ctx.settings.widgetTitle,     self.ctx.settings.widgetTitle);
var error_msg_translated = $translate.instant('widgets.input-widgets.update-failed');
```

To understand the *utils-service* you can see the source [Here](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/master/ui/src/app/common/utils.service.js) and to get a video tutorial on Custom Translations [Here](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/custom-translation/)